# How to create a task that takes a list of one type and converts it to another type

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am trying to convert a list of some type to a list of another type and the lists are really big so converting I image would be pretty computational heavy with all the new objects created and such so I want to fire this off on a task so I can await the result. I am not entirely new to async code in C# but maybe this is the first time I have run across needing to create a async compatible method like this one before.

The code below gives me red squiggles and error's it seems no matter which way I write the code. Can somebody please look this over and tell me what part I am writing wrong.

I have tried to explicitly state the parameters in lambda form and I have tried creating a Func<,> but nothing seems to work.`

```
    public async Task<ComplexTypeAdapters.GetQuestionsByTestTakenResult> Client4_GetQuestionsByTestTaken( long? testResultId, string cultureTag )
    {
        var result = await Context.Client4_GetQuestionsByTestTaken(testResultId, cultureTag).ToListAsync();

        //var list = new List<ComplexTypeAdapters.GetQuestionsByTestTakenResult>( );

        return await Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
        {
            var list = new List<ComplexTypeAdapters.GetQuestionsByTestTakenResult>( );
            foreach( Client4_GetQuestionsByTestTaken_Result one in result )
            {
                var res = new ComplexTypeAdapters.GetQuestionsByTestTakenResult
                {
                    Id = one.id, App = one.App, Ver = one.Ver, Name = one.Name, Script = one.Script
                };
                try
                {
                    res.SampleDocs = XElement.Parse( one.sampleDocs );
                } catch( Exception )
                {
                    res.SampleDocs = null;
                }
                try
                {
                    res.Instructions = XElement.Parse( one.instructions );
                } catch( Exception )
                {
                    res.Instructions = null;
                }
                try
                {
                    res.SampleDocsFolder = XElement.Parse( one.sampleDocsFolder );
                } catch( Exception )
                {
                    res.SampleDocsFolder = null;
                }
                list.Add( res );
            }
            return list;
        } );

        return returnList;
    }
```

Comment: And what's the compiler error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to fire this off on a task so I can await the result

I'm assuming that you're wanting to free up the UI thread during this processing.

In that case, assuming you *already have* the synchronous code written as `Client4_GetQuestionsByTestTaken`, then you can just do:

```
await Task.Run(() => Client4_GetQuestionsByTestTaken(testResultId, cultureTag));
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I have always used Task.Factory.StartNew() as I thought it was the recommended but I keep seeing people using Task.Run a lot now. I will have to look up the difference later, but your solution works great. I think I just got brain-dead for a minute.

Comment: I have a few blogs on `StartNew`: [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and [Delegate Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html), which go into more detail on why `Task.Run` is preferred (unless you're using a custom `TaskScheduler`).